# Indian Passport first page ripped - is this considered 'damaged'?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, damaged-passports

[image]

Hi All, My passport first page got ripped. Front side of this page has a Indian emblem and backside is a blank with no stamps or Visas. Other pages including visas, personal details, POE stamps everything looks good. Basically a brand new passport with more than 7 years validity. Will this be considered as damaged? Please help me with your answers ASAP as I have a travel plan to India end of this month for my own wedding.

This damage happened accidentally when I was scanning the pages.

Comment: In some countries the invalidated (normally by renewing) passports are marked by ripping or cutting of a fragment of the first page (you can than keep such passport as souvenir) so you should expect some border guards to doubt the validity of such a password.

Comment: Most of the security features, which passport forensic investigators check, aren't on the pages but on the laminated first and last pages of the passport. If they aren't tampered with, you will go through. But the passport officer may question you about the torn page.

Comment: What did you end up doing? If you got a re-issued passport, did you have to get the visa stamped also?

Answer (score 37):

### Be Safe: Get a New Passport

I think it is better to err on the safe side here and get a  replacement passport. Whilst it might be a minor damage, page rips aren't usually considered as wear from normal usage.

### Identify a Damaged Passport

I checked the definitions of damaged passports and there seems to be a common denominator across countries. A distinction is made between normal wear and damage. Turns out that **significant tears are not considered normal wear**. Quoting from the [US Department of State, Bureau of Foreign Affairs website](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/FAQs.html):

> If your passport has been significantly damaged, especially the book cover or the page displaying your personal data and photo, you will need to apply for a new passport. Conditions that may constitute damage requiring you to replace your passport include water damage, a significant tear, unofficial markings on the data page, missing visa pages (torn out), a hole punch, or other injuries.
>
> Normal wear of a U.S. passport is expected and likely does not constitute "damage."  For instance normal wear includes the bend of a passport after being carried in your back pocket or fanning of the visa pages after extensive opening and closing.

#### Indian Regulation

According to the [Indian Ministry of External Affairs, Consular, Passport and Visa Division](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports):

> **Q1: What is the definition of damaged passport?**
>
> A: Damaged passport is classified further based on the extent of damage, i.e.:
>
> - Damaged Passport - Passport number is readable, name is legible and photo is intact
> - Damaged beyond recognition

Luckily enough though, because yours is not extensively damaged, you can apply for an urgent replacement passport under the Tatkaal scheme:

> **Q6: My passport booklet is damaged. I want to go abroad on urgent basis. What should I do?**
>
> A: In case your passport has not been damaged beyond recognition, i.e. passport number is legible, name is legible and photo is intact, then you can apply for re-issue of passport under the Tatkaal scheme. But, if passport has been damaged beyond recognition, then you cannot apply under the Tatkaal scheme. In that case, you need to visit Passport Officer at your nearest Passport Seva Kendra to get the passport on urgent basis.

Comment: Bah, wrote out my answer after research and then realised it's almost word for word the same as yours.  Deleted mine and upvoting your one.