# Can I expect problems flying to the Netherlands with a damaged Albanian passport?

Tags: passports

My passport has been damaged by my dog. He ate a little of it.

[image: dog chewed passport]

I have to fly to the Netherlands for a few days. Is there likely to be a problem?

Comment: I removed the image with your personal details. Better safe than sorry. :)

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged/

Comment: The passowords are purposely damaged on invalidation, therefore damaged password is considered invalid, but that damage doesn't look like any of those purposely made damages. However, if you meet a Vogon, it's always possible they will take 'damaged' too literarily. If you have time, exchanging that would be reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Very much like in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/39265/22140) I would say that it's better to be safe. Hence, in my opinion, you should get a new passport.

I tried looking for an Albanian source of information on the topic but could not find any (probably due to my lack of knowledge of Albanian). The best definition of damaged passport I could find is given in the the US Department of State, Bureau of Foreign Affairs website, according to which **your passport is considered as damaged**, and hence should be replaced. [Their page on the topic](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/FAQs.html) explicitly mentions damage on the book cover (emphasis mine):

> If your passport has been significantly damaged, **especially the book cover** or the page displaying your personal data and photo, you will need to apply for a new passport. Conditions that may constitute damage requiring you to replace your passport include water damage, a significant tear, unofficial markings on the data page, missing visa pages (torn out), a hole punch, or other injuries.

Since you are travelling in a few days, there might be an express renewal service for people in your situation. You might want to check this with your local authorities.