# Indian passport with two missing (ripped out) pages - should I get a new one to enter the US?

Tags: usa, passports, india, legal, indian-citizens

I have got a passport in very good condition with two inner pages totally ripped out (they are missing). I had my Schengen visa issued on those pages with a few stamps but now that visa has expired.

Does this situation invalidate my passport? 
should I apply for new passport now or I can make this passport work?

I need to fly to US in July.

Comment: Do not take the risk of being refused entry. Get a new passport.

Comment: When you reported this to the Schengen consulate that issued your visa, did you receive confirmation that the visas had been cancelled?

Comment: As @jpatokalsays, missing pages are usually unacceptable. Some countries are known (or thought to be) more  inflexible tan others - and the US is on the bad end of that range.  [I had some roughing and a **slight** tear along one page edge when outgoing to China.  NZ outgoing customs advised me to get a new passport asap. They said it was OK for China but would be rejected if I tried to enter the US].

Comment: @DavidRicherby I consider that  Priya's case is a superset of mine. She mentioned wanting to enter the US in July. I was told that the US would reject a passport that was mildly defaced - the reason given being that potential tampering was indicated. I have no doubt that anyone who would have rejected mine for that reason would absolutely certainly and with malice aforethought (and both smoking barrels) reject one with missing pages. Anyone who does not share my certainty is welcome to test US Customs & Homeland Security's mettle - but all reports are that they will not be found wanting. Alas

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged/39265#39265

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Fair enough. Actually, I'd not noticed that the question specifically mentioned the US, which makes your example extremely relevant. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a valuable and validated comments. I Really appreciate. @ Russell McMahon

Comment: As a curiosity, why oh why were pages ripped from your passport? Who did this? Why?

Answer (score 36):

Missing pages generally **invalidate a passport**.  Depending on how cleanly they were removed, a casual inspection might not notice, but if noticed, you will at the *very least* be in for some heavy questioning, and may be denied boarding/entry.  Applying for a new passport is *strongly* advisable.

Comment: Worth noting that pages are often numbered and so missing pages have good chances to be noticed even if they were removed very cleanly.

Comment: _I'd bet anyone handling tens to hundreds passports a day will sense immediately that your passport is unusually thin._ (Passports are made of really thick and heavy paper. May are thick with visas, but very few are thin. I, for example, have learned, over the years, to tell almost unmistakably by the weight of it whether the jewell case I'm holding in my hand has a cd in it or not - and I'm just a casual user!)

Comment: @PavelPetrman Every passport design is different, so I doubt you would notice the weight difference that quickly. None the less I of course totally agree that getting a new passport is definitely the best idea.

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion, when in doubt it's always better to **err on the safe side and get a new passport**. Last thing you want to happen is to get bounced back at immigration checks due to a damaged passport. Quoting from [my other answer on the topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged/39265#39265):

> I checked the definitions of damaged passports and there seems to be a common denominator across countries. A distinction is made between normal wear and damage. Turns out that **significant tears are not considered normal wear**.

You are in luck though as you can apply for an urgent replacement under the Tatkaal scheme, since, according to the Indian definition of damaged passports, yours isn't damaged beyond recognition. Indeed, quoting from the [Indian Ministry of External Affairs, Consular, Passport and Visa Division](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports):

> **Q1: What is the definition of damaged passport?**
>
> A: Damaged passport is classified further based on the extent of damage, i.e.:
>
> - Damaged Passport - Passport number is readable, name is legible and photo is intact
> - Damaged beyond recognition
>
> **Q6: My passport booklet is damaged. I want to go abroad on urgent basis. What should I do?**
>
> A: In case your passport has not been damaged beyond recognition, i.e. passport number is legible, name is legible and photo is intact, then you can apply for re-issue of passport under the Tatkaal scheme. But, if passport has been damaged beyond recognition, then you cannot apply under the Tatkaal scheme. In that case, you need to visit Passport Officer at your nearest Passport Seva Kendra to get the passport on urgent basis.