# Small rip in one of the internal pages in Indian passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, international-travel

I live in the US and need to travel to India next month. I just realized one of the internal pages is ripped. Does that mean I cannot travel ?

Passport processing is taking upto 8 weeks and tatkal is not possible unless you have an emergency. Please advice

Comment: Is it a blank page that is ripped? If it is, I would not bother too much.

Comment: It has an immigration stamp from previous visits but otherwise blank

Comment: I applied for tatkal in Singapore without any emergency letter. it just costs you a premium rate. but yeah in just 3 days i got a new passport. Consult the high commission on the situation, they may assist.

Comment: How small is the rip? Can you post a picture? If you do remember to hide your personal details.

Comment: In the US it is very clear tatkal is at the discretion of the embassy and is only granted if there is a death in the family or some emergency medical situation....have no issue paying the additional fee.

Comment: @JErNanO Ok I have a picture but don't see how to post ...can you please help

Comment: @RachnaMalhotra You can post it to some place like imgur and someone with enough rep can edit it into your question so everyone can easily see it. Just edit your question to include the raw link (something like http://i.imgur.com/xxx.jpg) and someone will fix it for you.

Comment: I don't think  it's going to be a problem, unless it is the main page/visa etc which has your photograph and information about you. Think about it like this, what if the tear happens at the airport, would you still not go ahead with your travel plans?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47786/indian-passport-with-two-missing-ripped-out-pages-should-i-get-a-new-one-to?rq=1 Check this question, it states something similar to your case in one of the comments. I still think, you will not have any issues getting out of the US to India. Maybe, just maybe you might have trouble getting into the States. So to eliminate that risk, you could get your passport re-issued while you are in India.

Comment: Ok I was thinking India may not allow me to enter rather than coming back home to the US. Something to think about. Thanks!

Comment: @RachnaMalhotra [See this meta post on how to upload pictures to posts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: An update: I went to the us border and customs office and showed them the passport. They said the US will not care about it because the passport is valid and anyways the demographic pages are fine. What in their mind was more important was having the green card with me