# Indian passport threading coming off

Tags: passports, india, damaged-passports

My Indian passport threading is coming off i.e. the cover of the passport is coming off, there are only 2 threads remaining.

Will it be a problem at the airport when going abroad ? Also anyone who has experience of getting a replacement passport fairly quick ? Because I need to get a passport in like 15 days.

Comment: It is [unpredictable](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/where-will-a-damaged-passport-get-you-1320769.html)

Comment: There might be, with an overzealous immigration officer, as most of them thinks of themselves as God. Indian passport quality is literally shit. The info pagr lamination comes off, the number punchednin second half top with tiny needle holes gets damaged by rust, threads get worn.

Comment: @DavChana I know that Indian passports and their systems are pathetic. Just curious if I can travel with carefully handling the passport ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indian Passport first page ripped - is this considered 'damaged'?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged)

Comment: What did you end up doing? I am in a similar situation

Answer (score 2):

It is debatable whether the damage you describe makes any difference but since no longer in mint condition there is a risk that some official will object (if only to add some variety into yet another otherwise boring day). Indian passports are not very durable and some receive a huge amount of use, meaning that most officials will have seen tatty examples before yours.

The thread is part of the security features of the passport hence you might want to attempt just enough stitching of your own to hold the pages together and retain the last of the thread.

Since apparently 'marginal' it is quite likely that you would be warned to replace it before actually being banned from travelling.

However, India recognises [two types of passport damage](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports) and yours is the less serious one so your passport is eligible for the Tatkaal scheme for replacement. This though is not available everywhere (for example not Canada). For a fee of around ₹5,000 a replacement passport may be issued in around eight working days - so just about enough time if 15 days is your upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had an issue with them not accepting my damaged passport. Make sure that you don't lose any documents that are in the passport. You might need to create a medium-sized scene if you encounter an officer who thinks he is God.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer ! Was your damage the same as I described in my question?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the immigration official will ask few questions and let you to go. However I would not prefer that route.

I had similar issue with photo page on passport started to come off, and I noticed 2 days before my travel back home, showed and discussed with a friend, we thought in terms of any travel, it is wiser to just go to any Indian Embassy get it fixed, or apply for replacement passport.

Went to Indian embassy, they verified my documents, and fixed the little tear in the passport.

Just imagine, if any immigration official dont allow you to travel, or just putting you for further inquiry may lead to missing your flight, or re-booking flights can cost you more than taking little extra caution to fix the passport.