# My passport was detached from the front cover but all the pages are intact. what shall i do?

Tags: indian-citizens, india

My passport was detached from the front cover but all the pages are intact. I have an Indian passport and wants to travel from Philippines to India, is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You should check with the immigration authorities in the Philippines if you travel document is valid. If not, You have to get a new (new passport from the Indian embassy) one and renew you Residency permit/Visa in the Philippines before you travel (if you want to return to the Philippines)

Answer (score 2):

Immigration on torn passport is difficult. I had a similar incident when the front page of my passport had a little torn. One of my friend scared me of issues while traveling with torn passport, so I visited Indian Embassy in New York City.

I visited the Indian embassy with all the necessary documents to request for a duplicate passport request, they verified all of my documents and sealed the passport.

See my answer earlier @ [Indian passport threading coming off](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87562/indian-passport-threading-coming-off/90811#90811)