# Procedure to get a new passport when only binding of the old passport is damaged

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen. The binding of my passport has been damaged and the cover is totally detached from the pages. None of the pages or the cover itself is damaged. All my details are intact.

I was traveling to USA and they refused me boarding due to this damaged passport. How can I get a new passport? I looked at the "damaged passport" section in the Passport Seva Kendra website but it looks like the options given there do not match the issue I am facing.

Comment: India classifies damages in two categories a) Damages - when Passport No., name and photo is visible b) Damages beyond repair when these are not visible. As your cover has come off, the details will probably be visible so you need to replace a "damaged" (NOT damaged beyond repair) passport. You should be able to apply under Tatkal for this. There are a ton of questions about damaged Indian passports on this website, please have a look.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/87562/50234 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/96036/50234

Comment: Also see the answer to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged

Comment: That you were refused boarding due to its condition should be sufficient reason to [apply to have your passport re-issued](https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/docAdvisor/reissuePassport)

Comment: Di you have to get the visa stamped in your new passport?

Answer (score 6):

You were refused boarding due to the condition of your passport; that should be sufficient justification to [request a re-issue](https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports) of your passport.

The binding and cover are part of a passport's security features and while yours is not damaged beyond recognition, it is still not acceptable for its intended use, as you unfortunately discovered.