# My Indian friend is on tour visa and he had to tear last page of his passport, would he face any issue?

Tags: passports, india

My friend (Indian) is in another country and he had to tear last page of his passport because that page captured some water droplets and if he wouldn't have teared it would had affected other pages as well. I suggest him to visit Indian embassy in that country and talk to them.

What do you think its fine to his passport would be considered damaged and he needs to get it fixed? How much time it take to get new passport in a different country?

Comment: To be sure I'm understanding correctly, has your friend torn a page out of his passport because it got wet?

Comment: You ask how long it would take to get a new passport in a different country - please could you tell us what country your friend is in so we can answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Procedure to get a new passport when only binding of the old passport is damaged](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117000/procedure-to-get-a-new-passport-when-only-binding-of-the-old-passport-is-damaged)

Comment: @Traveller I'm not sure that's a good dupe. That passport has a detached cover and has already been refused for travel; this one has a torn page and it's not clear _how_ torn.

Comment: He shouldn't have done that. he should have dried the wet page, while holding the passport open to avoid getting water on the other pages.

Comment: +100 @DJClayworth, unfortunately he has done so and now needs a fix...

Comment: @FreeMan Yes you are completely correct.

Comment: I think he has to go to the nearest Indian embassy or consulate, show them the passport, and ask what to do and how long it might take.

Comment: @ChrisH why did you delete your answer? It seems perfectly correct.

Comment: @phoog I decided there was too much assumption (the description of quite what was done to the passport isn’t too clear to me, and I have no idea whether processing times in Germany are representative of those for whichever unnamed country this person is in)

Comment: @phoog that said, on reading again I think the description of thr damage is less ambiguous than it seemed to me earlier, and the possibility that timings aren’t representative is unavoidable without that information and flagged up in the answer, so I’ve undeleted it.

Answer (score 3):

A passport with a page torn out of it will certainly be considered damaged (at best), and is very likely to cause problems if presented to border agents. Your friend should replace the passport.

According to the [Embassy of India in Germany](https://www.indianembassyberlin.gov.in/pages?id=eyJpdiI6IklITHQ3eUFtRDFQanJmb3JpTmY3T3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQ1lrZEJMMFEwNm5CeWIrV2JuVWZndz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWY4YmRiNWVhMzI1NzllZjU0ZjdkYTA3M2Q0MTU2M2Y3YWYzOGQ2YTQ1M2E4YzAxZWRiZWM3YjcwNzUzMTViYiJ9&subid=eyJpdiI6Ik12NjRJTllvTW1RbkRBOTBVRUlpdVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUlYraFJUcE5GVUtmV0FhOVA5RmtIZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZGY5M2I5MDIwMDgyNjAwMDhjMmQ0NTc2M2YyMDYwY2E3Y2VmZjViODE2MTQyMGUxNjI4MTU5M2E3NGZmNTE2MSJ9&nextid=eyJpdiI6IlZTTTBmcURVNkx6dEhpb1BMZHZqM2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSzRLT2ZUaXEwd0MwNEJkTUpVZWxJdz09IiwibWFjIjoiYjQ5ZGQxZTVhOGUwN2U1NzBiZjIzNGRlZTBjZjgwYTg2MGRkMDkwNDgwZjg5ZTEzYzNlNDg3Y2U2YzY5NzA5MCJ9), replacing a passport typically takes around 2-3 weeks. The processing time may be different in other countries.