# Are there chances of Schengen visa rejection for this kind of cellotaped passport?

Tags: visas, schengen

[image]
Hello All, 
Today I have applied for Schengen tourist  Visa for a solo trip (I'm leaving India on 29th of June). Please have a look at the attached image. The cover page is slightly torn at the upper end and is cellotaped to prevent further damage. Rest all other pages and details are very much legible and intact. What do you guys think? Will they reject and ask me to get fresh passport and again apply? Did this happen with any of you before? Thanks in advance for reading my query.

Comment: Honestly I think India needs to get a better company to produce their passports. Virtually every damaged passport question on this site has been about an Indian visa. Instead of cellotape I recommend you use **invisible super glue**.

Comment: Questions that ask about "chances" are considered opinion based and may be closed. In you case, even if you get a visa, making a journey with such a passort may prove to be a hassle. We have mutiple questions about damaged Indian passports like [detached cover](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/96036/50234), [threading coming out](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/87562/50234), [damaged binding](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/117000/50234).

Comment: If you have already applied, the question is moot. If VFS has accepted your passport without comment, that;s one hurdle out of the way. However, as Red Baron suggests, a damaged passport can be a hassle at any airport immigration counter. I would suggest that you get a replacement passport as soon as you are able.

Comment: Got my visa approved in 2 working days. But thanks guys for your advise, I would get my passport reissued.