# Damage passport

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, india

My mother was travelling from India to US and airline person pointed out that her indian passport is damaged. After multiple request they let her travel but asked her to replace the damaged passport at Indian embassy in US. When i assessed the damage, i realized it's not really that bad. I am attaching the picture [image: here].It seems some paper has come out but the strings inside is still intact. No one in US immigration objected on port of entry. My question is, is it fine to continue with this passport and replace it when she go back to india sometime next year or i should get it change it asap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indian passport threading coming off](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87562/indian-passport-threading-coming-off). I think damaged (Indian) passport may need its own canonical. Too many of [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87562/indian-passport-threading-coming-off)

Comment: If you can change it quickly why wait? It’s only a few dollars, peace of mind is more important than a few dollars and definitely way cheaper than the cost incurred if you’re denied boarding and have to reschedule.

Comment: i would prefer the same but she has to travel to Australia in 6 weeks and i am afraid it might not be enough time to get the passport back.

Comment: What answer can we give you? You already know that your mother's passport is sufficiently damaged that it's causing her problems. If she doesn't get a new one, she's risking not being allowed to travel. This is clearly a real danger, given the difficulty she had on her most recent trip.

Comment: I am sorry if I didn’t put my point properly. My main reason to put up the question was to see if someone else has the same experience. The damage(as in picture) doesn’t look severe and i was hoping it can last for couple of trips. It seems i really annoyed you here, apologies!