# Seal in Passport is slightly smudged

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, passports, canada, applications

Gov seal in my passport in slight smudged as showing in the attachment. however bio  and all other pages are perfectly good. Im going for the Canada bio this week. Will this be a consider as damaged passport and the reason for VFS or Embassy to reject my visa appliction.  [image: Passport seal]

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87562/indian-passport-threading-coming-off

Comment: It is a damage or it was so in origin? Personally I had worst stamps on my passports (the worst I had: USA, you see only the signature and handwritten code, to see the stamp you need a lot of light (I was the first client of the day).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes it is how i received initially. Not worried all these days. But now im getting worried as my application will be submitted to VFS.