# Water Smudge Marks on Passport_ Can it be Considered as 'Damaged'?

Tags: passports

Due to an accidental pouring of water on my passport, the very first page containing the stamp/seal of the Regional Passport Officer (RPO) has become smudged in nature.

- Can this be considered as 'damaged'?
- Do I need to re-apply for my 'just renewed' passport?

Thanks for reading the question(s).
Hope to get relevant answers in the shortest possible turn-around-time.
Regards

Comment: You forgot to state what country issued the passport.

Comment: If it doesn't show any personal info, you might include a photograph to show where and what you mean

Comment: Related http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged