# Can I Travel with this slightly Damaged Indian passport

Tags: india, damaged-passports

I have a flight in 3 days and I want to confirm whether I can safely travel with this slightly damaged passwort, I didn't even noticed until yesterday that it was torn in the corner like this , I have flight from hyd , are they strict about these[image: Image of passport]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indian Passport first page ripped - is this considered 'damaged'?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged)

Comment: no it didn't because that was highly ripped whereas mine was slight damage

Comment: The link to the Indian Ministry of External Affairs in the answer contains the official advice on *damaged passports*.